Step in Granvilles proof of Sylvester-Schur Theorem
Granville proves in his book Number Theory Revealed: A Masterclass the Sylvester-Schur-Theorem. Here is a part of the proof:

Proof. [...] Now if $n \geq 3 k$, then, by exercise 4.14 .2 of appendix 4D,
$$
\frac{\left(4^4 / 3^3\right)^k}{e k} \leq\binom{ 4 k}{k} \leq\binom{ n+k}{k} \leq k^{\frac{1}{2} k^{3 / 4}} 4^{k-1}
$$
which is false for all $k \geq 1$.

Here is the used exercise:

Exercise 4.14 .2: Prove for $N\geq M$
$$
 \frac{\left(\frac{N}{e}\right)^N}{\left(\frac{M}{e}\right)^M} \leq \frac{N!}{M!} \leq \frac{\left(\frac{N}{e}\right)^{N+1}}{\left(\frac{M}{e}\right)^{M+1}}.
$$

I proved the exercise and tried to unterstand its usage in the proof, but I do not get the first inequality (the rest is clear to me). This is what I get:
For $N=4k$ and $M=3k$
$$
\frac{\left(\frac{4k}{e}\right)^{4k}}{\left(\frac{3k}{e}\right)^{3k}}=   \frac{(4k)^{4k}}{e^{4k}}  \frac{e^{3k}}{(3k)^{3k}} = k^k\frac{\left(4^4 / 3^3\right)^k}{e^k} \color{red}{\overset{???}{\leq}} \frac{(4k)!}{k!(3k)!} =\binom{4k}{k}
$$
I am not able to show the inequality marked in red. Note that I get a slightly different term, I get $k^k/e^k$ whereas in the proof by Granville he has $1/(ek)$.

The problem is that you're aiming for an incorrect inequality—but you're so close to having it! Note that your application of Exercise 4.14.2 actually gives
$$
k^k\frac{\left(4^4 / 3^3\right)^k}{e^k} \le \frac{(4k)!}{(3k)!},
$$
so that we should divide both sides by $k!$ to get
$$
\frac{k^k}{k!}\frac{\left(4^4 / 3^3\right)^k}{e^k} \le \binom{4k}{3k}.
$$
So the problem reduces to showing that
$$
\frac1{ek} \le \frac{k^k}{k!e^k} \quad\text{or equivalently}\quad
k! \le \Bigl( \frac ke \Bigr)^k ek,
$$
which is a consequence of Stirling's approximation.

Related to Stirling's approximation:
From an article by Karatsuba (2001), here is a two sided expression giving both upper and lower bounds for $n!$  In the article it is written for the Gamma function; it is due to Ramanujan.
$$  \sqrt \pi \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \left( 8 n^3 + 4 n^2 + n + \frac{1}{100}\right)^{1/6}  <  n!   <    \sqrt \pi \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \left( 8 n^3 + 4 n^2 + n + \frac{1}{30}\right)^{1/6}  $$
Karatsuba proved that  the number between $1/100$  and $1/30$  that gives the factorial exactly  increases monotonically, as a function of my $n$

